# Prove that the identity $\sum_{i=1}^n\underline u_i\underline u_i^{*T}=I_{n\times n}$ is valid for $n\times n$ hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the hermitian matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}5&10&0\\10&25&5\\0&5&5\end{bmatrix}$$ Its eigenvalues is $\lambda_1=30\;,\lambda_2=5\;,\lambda_3=0$ and its corresponding eigenvectors are: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}2\\5\\1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ , $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}-2\\1\\-1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ so we will have:
$$\begin{align}
&\underline u_1\underline u_1^{*T}+\underline u_2\underline u_2^{*T}+\underline u_3\underline u_3^{*T}=\\ 
&\frac{1}{30}
\begin{bmatrix}4&10&2\\10&25&5\\2&5&1\end{bmatrix}+
\frac{1}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\0&0&0\\-2&0&4\end{bmatrix}+
\frac{1}{6}
\begin{bmatrix}4&-2&2\\-2&1&-1\\2&-1&1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$ now I want to prove that this identity is verified for every $n\times n$ hermitian matrix. I have already tried for a special case $2\times 2$ hermitian matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and orthonormal eigenvectors $\underline v_1=\begin{bmatrix}v_{11}\\v_{12}\end{bmatrix}$ and $\underline v_2=\begin{bmatrix}v_{21}\\v_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ then
$$\begin{align}
\underline{v}_1\underline{v}_1^{*T}+\underline{v}_2\underline{v}_2^{*T}&=\begin{bmatrix}v_{11}\\v_{12}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_{11}^*&v_{12}^*\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}v_{21}\\v_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_{21}^*&v_{22}^*\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
v_{11}v_{11}^*+v_{21}v_{21}^* & v_{11}v_{12}^*+v_{21}v_{22}^* \\
v_{12}v_{11}^*+v_{22}v_{21}^* & v_{12}v_{12}^*+v_{22}v_{22}^* 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$
I wanted to use the properties of orthonormal eigenvectors:
$\langle \underline v_1.\underline v_1\rangle=v_{11}v_{11}^*+v_{12}v_{12}^*=1$
$\langle \underline v_2.\underline v_2\rangle=v_{21}v_{21}^*+v_{22}v_{22}^*=1$
$\langle \underline v_1.\underline v_2\rangle=v_{11}v_{21}^*+v_{12}v_{22}^*=0$
but as you see, I can't use!!!

Comment: you might want to look up the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: @user251257 but what you suggested me to study is about diagonilizing a hermitian matrix. I know it can be proved that every hermitian matrix is diagonalizable. for a $n\times n$ matrix simply write the $n$ orthonormal eigenvectors in the columns of the matrix $U$ and the $U^{*T}U$ will be an identity matrix from the fact that for $i,j$ we have $\langle \underline v_i.\underline v_i\rangle=1$ and $\langle \underline v_i.\underline v_j\rangle=0$ but this is different from my question

Comment: A $n\times n$ matrix $U$ is unitary iff $U^*U = UU^* = I_n$. Notice that for a square matrix the left inverse is also the right inverse.

Comment: @user251257 so you say the proof is as follows: I can easily place orthormal eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix $A$ in the columns of a matrix $U$ and easily prove that $U^*U=I$ and because the columns of $U$ are orthonormal $U$ is a unitary matrix so $UU^*=U^*U=I$ and now $UU^*=I$ follows that $\sum_{i=1}^n\underline u_i\underline u_i^{*T}=I_{n\times n}$

Comment: I know that is a property of unitary matrices we have $U^{-1}=U^*$

Comment: if you meant by ${u_i^*}^T$ complex conjugate and transpose, then yes. Aside: people usually only write $u_i^*$.

Comment: yes I was confused by the notation